# Removing "/usr/share/calendar/calendar.history" from appearing at the beginning of every new Terminal window

Tags: terminal, calendar

This is an weird one. About a year ago I was playing Mac Terminal easter eggs e.g. Star Wars, Emacs games, etc.

But there's one that I haven't been able to get rid of. If you type `cat /usr/share/calendar/calendar.history` in the Terminal you'll see a list of significant dates. I get about 5 delivered daily at the top of my Terminal. See below.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hY2NQ.png]

I haven't been able to get rid of this and it's driving me crazy. Does anyone have any ideas on how to get rid of this?

Comment: Try running `grep calendar  ~/.*  ~/*`  to see which profile file it is in then edit that file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the grep file by doing `defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES` then looking through some files.

At some point I had written `nano ~/.bash_profile` and included

`today=date "+%m/%d"`
`grep $today /usr/share/calendar/calendar.birthday`
`grep $today /usr/share/calendar/calendar.computer`
`grep $today /usr/share/calendar/calendar.history`
`grep $today /usr/share/calendar/calendar.lotr`
`grep $today /usr/share/calendar/calendar.music`